# Problem compiling React native project on ios

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, native, react-native-ios

I get errors of not finding the React/reactLog.h file and more files from various react native libraries.

Have tried cocapods and it says it is installing, but it seems as if it's not installed in any libraries.

The error is:

> 'FBSDKSharekit/FBSDKSharekit.h' file not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in any case you have to follow the instructions again from this link and double check everything:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk

However, in my opinion this error occurs if you don't download and put the `FacebookSDK` in your document folder and drag and drop it into your project. So check if you have downloaded it and put it there please. After Putting it there, you should go in your Xcode project in the `Library -> RCTFBSDK.xcodeproj` path and drag and drop `FBSDKSharekit` file from your facebook SDK folder(In your document folder) into the framework folder. You have to do the same thing with FBSDKCore and FBSDKLogin.

In addition you should check these two points:

1- FBSDK[Core, Login, Share]Kit.framework show up in the **Link Binary with Libraries** section of your build target's Build Phases.

2- Make sure that `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` is in the Framework Search Path of your build target's Build Settings.

Then try to clean and compile the project. I hope it helps you.

Comment: thank you so much for commenting the problem was solved before Ive read it